# Punctuation after title and Beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, punctuation

I'm trying to customize the bibliography for a presentation. I'm running into trouble with the punctuation after the title. As a MWE, I wrote the following `biblatex.cfg` file:

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{giveninits=true, uniquename=false}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author}%
    \setunit{\labelnamepunct}%
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \setunit{\addperiod\space}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
    \setunit{\addperiod\space}\newblock
    \printfield{note}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\newbibmacro*{volume+chapter+pages}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \newunit%
    \printfield{chapter}%
    \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
    \printfield{pages}}
```

There should be a period after the title. However, Beamer inserts a comma. Other classes (e.g., `scrartcl`) do insert a period after the title. Beamer correctly inserts a period between the publisher and the note though.

I tried modifying the bibmacro `title`, removing all instances of `\newunit`, to no avail.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with how `beamer` patches some of `biblatex`'s macros to include the colouring.

In `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty` we find

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}
    {%[...]
     \apptocmd{\abx@macro@title}
       {\ifcsundef{abx@field@title}{}{\midsentence\newunitpunct}%
        \newblock\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}}{}{}}
    {}}
```

This shows that the `title` macro is changed to always print a `\newunitpunct` after the title (not even in a `\setunit`, the punctuation is printed immediately).

You can fix this by resetting the `title` macro in `\AtBeginDocument` to its original form from `biblatex.def` and adding the colouring macros.

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewbibmacro*{title}{%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry title}%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\iffieldundef{title}}
      and
      test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
    }
      {}
      {\printtext[title]{%
         \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
         \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
         \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
       \newunit}%
    \printfield{titleaddon}}
    \newblock\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}}
```